# Find values in file, between keywords, using python

Tags: python, file

I have some file, which have some data like this:

```
begin of file
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
end of file
```

I want read this file, so I have tried:

```
filename = open('file','r')
for line in filename:
    print line
```

But now I need to search the keywords like 'begin of file' and 'end of file' in the txt file, then save the values between the 2 keywords to a list.
I have tried this:

```
Listsave = []
filename = open('file', 'r')
for line in filename:
    if "begin of file" in line:
        listsave.append(line.next())
```

But it is seems like doesnt work.

How can I deal with that?
thanks a lot

Comment: modifying loop variable inside the loop (line.next()) is not good practice. You can set a binary variable to mark whether to record the lines

Comment: "But it is seems like doesnt work." How can you tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following approach which would make use of Python's CSV library to split your rows into suitable columns. This would then make it easier to support different delimiters or extra quoting if needed.

```
import StringIO, csv

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    begin = False
    rows = []

    for line in f_input:
        if line.startswith("end of file"):
            break
        elif begin:
            rows.append(next(csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(line))))
        elif line.startswith("begin of file"):
            begin = True

    print rows
```

So for the following type of input:

```
stuff
begin of file
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
end of file
more stuff
```

It would create:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], ['8', '9', '10'], ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("file") as file:
    data = file.read()
result = data.partition("begin of file")[2].rpartition("end of file")[0].strip().split(",")
print result
```

Result:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Comment: The read() method reads an entire file's contents into memory. Rpartition is essentially a more advanced split. While there is less code, I think this solution does a lot of unnecessary processing.

Comment: That is certainly a valid concern if the OP's file is especially large. Doesn't make much of a difference for the example they gave, though ;-)

Comment: That's true, just meant it as a general reference though.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getstringbetween(source, first, last):
try:
    start = source.index(first) + len(first)
    end = source.index(last, start)
    return source[start:end]
except ValueError:
    return ""
```

Usage:

```
print getstringbetween("abcdefg", "ab", "fg")
```

Returns:

"cde"

In your case, read all text to a string and call this function. Return the result to a list/array if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this. It marks whether we've passed the starting point, and breaks when we pass the finish point.

```
listsave = []
filename = open('file', 'r')
found = False
for line in filename:
    if not found:
        if 'begin of file' in line:
            found = True
    else:
        if 'end of file' in line:
            break
        listsave.append(line)
```

It's a bit early in the morning for me, so there may be a better solution.

EDIT:

Slightly cleaner version.

```
with open('file', 'r') as file:
    found = False
    saved = []
    for line in file:
        if not found:
            if 'begin of file' in line:
                found = True
        elif 'end of file' in line:
            break
        else:
            saved.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
filename = open('file', 'r')
Listsave = []
subline = ""
for line in filename:
    if "begin of file" in line:
        continue
    elif "end of file" in line:
        Listsave.append(subline)
    else:
        subline += line
print Listsave
```